# Get index of visible element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get index of `selected`class between visible elements in jquery.

```
<ul>
    <li>element 01</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 02</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 03</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 04</li>
    <li>element 05</li>
    <li>element 06</li>
    <li class="selected">element 07</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 08</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried these ways

```
console.log($('ul li.selected').index());
console.log($('ul li:visible.selected').index());
```

I want the number 3 for the example above: The index of the `.selected` element in the `ul` *ignoring* the elements that aren't visible.

Comment: You can determine if your elem has a  certain CSS style with `($('li#myId').css('display') == 'none')`, same with class using `hasClass`

Comment: What are you expecting as both of those lines output 6 which is the index of the li containing 'element 07'?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Why "between visible elements"? What number are you expecting? 6? 3?

Comment: I need to get index of elements. @Alicia

Comment: I expect the number 3 to return @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Sorry, question wasn't totally clear. But what I meant was, presuming you already know how to use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/), you can then just use `hasClass`/ `css` with that, should work fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector) on the result of selecting the visible elements, passing in the selected element (or a jQuery object containing it). `index` will find the index of the element within the jQuery set (the visible elements):

```
var index = $("ul li:visible").index($("ul li.selected"));
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log($("ul li:visible").index($("ul li.selected")));
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>element 01</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 02</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 03</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 04</li>
    <li>element 05</li>
    <li>element 06</li>
    <li class="selected">element 07</li>
    <li style="display: none">element 08</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```